# Restart Systemd unit after dependency

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04, web-applications, maintenance, automatic-updates

I have a web application that is started by `systemd`. It uses Postgresql as database, so it rely on it. Here is the unit file of my web application (I have remove the un-relevant/sensitive parts):

```
[Unit]
Description=xxxx
Requires=postgresql.service
After=network.target postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
SyslogIdentifier=xx-service
User=yyy
Group=zzz
ExecStart=/opt/.../xx
WorkingDirectory=/opt/xx
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Host os is Ubuntu server 16.04.

I recently had an event where the web application was not running in the morning when I returned to work. After checking the logs, I discovered the service was stopped by `systemd` because `postgresql` had an update. Apparently `aptitude` stopped `postgresql` before the upgrade and restarted it rigth after the update. When I logged into the machine it was running.

But `systemd` decided to stop my web application before stopping `postgresql`, which is nice, but didn't restart the web app it after it restarted `postgresql`.

How to instruct `systemd` to restart the appliation after `postgresql` service is restarted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `PartOf`:

> PartOf= Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to
>   stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the
>   units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that
>   this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the
>   listed units.
>
> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show
>   as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. ConsistsOf=
>   dependency cannot be specified directly.

Add `PartOf=postgresql.service` to the unit file of your web application, reload `systemctl-daemon` and test.

And to address the situation where your web application will have to start automatically after `postgresql.service` gets started, you could combine `PartOf` with `Wants`, but in `postgresql`'s unit file:

> Wants= A weaker version of Requires=. Units listed in this option will
>   be started if the configuring unit is. However, if the listed units
>   fail to start or cannot be added to the transaction, this has no
>   impact on the validity of the transaction as a whole. This is the
>   recommended way to hook start-up of one unit to the start-up of
>   another unit.
>
> Note that dependencies of this type may also be configured outside of
>   the unit configuration file by adding symlinks to a .wants/ directory
>   accompanying the unit file. For details, see above.

Comment: This works if i do `systemctl restart postgresql` but not if I `systemctl stop postgresql` then `systemctl start postgresql` as the automatic update will do.

Comment: I used `WantedBy=` as I didn't want to mess system components (ubuntu provided unit file) and now it works. Also I think its a more modulare approach. @13dimitar Thanks for you help !